# Append a tag before img tag

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have the below code. I am trying to append a element before image tag. It works, but it always replace previous content with the last content. I tried to use $i to separate the content. But, I am not quite sure how to implement it. Any suggestion?

```
preg_match_all('#src="(?:.*/)?(.*?)"#', $content, $match);

 foreach($match[0] as $k => $v){
        $replace = '<a href="'.$v.'"><img src="'.$v.'" /></a>';
        $content = preg_replace('#<\s*img.*?src="(?:[^"]+/)?(.*?)".*?>#s', $replace, $content);

 }
```